# Cómo crear una columna si se cumple una condición en otra en R

Tags: r, condiciones, dataframe

Tengo una dataframe  `df` que luce así:

```
|Year    | Name     |Posicion     |Calification   |
---------------------------------------------------
|2030    |Colombia  |Normal       |0.6            |
```

Y necesito que agregar una nueva columna llamada `Competencia` que dependa de los valores de la columna `Calification` de la siguiente forma:

Si `Calification` esta en el intervalo [0,1) entonces `Competencia` debe tener el string "Bajo"
Si `Calification` esta en el intervalo [1,2) entonces `Competencia` debe tener el string "Bajo a medio"
Si `Calification` esta en el intervalo [2,3) entonces `Competencia` debe tener el string "Medio a alto"
Si `Calification` esta en el intervalo [3,4) entonces `Competencia` debe tener el string "Alto"
Si `Calification` esta en el intervalo [4,5] entonces `Competencia` debe tener el string "Extremadamente alto"
En otro caso `Competencia` debe tener el string "Fuera de rango"

Con este código pude lograrlo:

```
 if (df["Calification"]>=0 & df["Calification"]<1) {
        df["Competencia"] = rep("Bajo", nrow(df))
        } else if (df["Calification"]>=1 & df["Calification"]<2) {
        df["Competencia"] = rep("Bajo a medio", nrow(df))  
        } else if (df["Calification"]>=2 & df["Calification"]<3) {
        df["Competencia"] = rep("Medio a alto", nrow(df))  
        } else if (df["Calification"]>=3 & df["Calification"]<4) {
        df["Competencia"] = rep("Alto", nrow(df))  
        }else if (df["Calification"]>=4 & df["Calification"]<=5){
        df["Competencia"] = rep("Extremandamente alto", nrow(df)) 
        }else{
          df["Competencia"] = rep("Fuera de rango", nrow(df))
        }
```

Teniendo un dataframe así:

```
|Year    | Name     |Posicion     |Calification   |Competencia |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|2030    |Colombia  |Normal       |0.6            |Bajo        |
```

Ahora, lo que necesito es ayuda para generalizar este código si df tiene la siguiente forma:

```
|Year    | Name     |Posicion     |Calification   |
---------------------------------------------------
|2030    |Colombia  |Normal       |0.6            |
|2030    |Chile     |Normal       |4.6            |
|2030    |Mexico    |Normal       |3.2            |
|2030    |Peru      |Normal       |1.2            |
|2030    |Uruguay   |Normal       |0.8            |
```

Podrían ayudarme con esto? De antemano, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## La solución

```
library(tidyverse) #Para crear tribbles
library(fuzzyjoin) # Para hacer joins con condiciones personalizadas
```

Aquí una versión reproducible de tus datos:

```
tribble(~Year,  ~Name,      ~Posicion,     ~Calification,
         2030,  "Colombia",  "Normal",       0.6,        
         2030,  "Chile",     "Normal",       4.6,        
         2030,  "Mexico",    "Normal",       3.2,        
         2030,  "Peru",      "Normal",       1.2,        
         2030,  "Uruguay",   "Normal",       0.8) -> datos
```

Una tabla que define las condiciones

```
tribble(~piso, ~techo, ~resultado, 
            0,      1, "Bajo", 
            1,      2, "Medio", 
            2,      3, "Medio alto", 
            3,      4, "Alto",
            4,      5, "Extremadamente alto") -> intervalo
```

Los unimos:

```
fuzzy_left_join(datos,     
                intervalo, 
                by = c("Calification" = "piso", 
                       "Calification" = "techo"), 
                match_fun = list(`>=`, `<`))
```

Y obtenemos:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 7
   Year Name     Posicion Calification  piso techo resultado          
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              
1  2030 Colombia Normal            0.6     0     1 Bajo               
2  2030 Chile    Normal            4.6     4     5 Extremadamente alto
3  2030 Mexico   Normal            3.2     3     4 Alto               
4  2030 Peru     Normal            1.2     1     2 Medio              
5  2030 Uruguay  Normal            0.8     0     1 Bajo
```

## ¿Por qué usar un join y no expresiones condicionales?

> Rule of Representation: Fold knowledge into data so program logic can be stupid and robust.

### 1. Por la forma en la que fallan

Cuando haces un join hay un lado izquierdo y un lado derecho: las dos tablas que estás uniendo. Casi siempre esperas que el resultado del join tenga la misma cantidad de filas que tu lado izquierdo. Si el resultado es más "largo" que el original entonces hay valores que hacen match con más de una condición, tienes un problema y lo puedes corregir a tiempo.

Si en el resultado de match tienes NA entonces hay algunos valores que no cumplen ninguna condición y tienes que ver que pasa.

### 2. Porque separas la lógica de los datos

Como las condiciones están en una estructura de datos aparte es más fácil agregar o cambiar condiciones. Es más simple editar una tabla que editar código enredado, con muchos paréntesis y comas. Hasta puedes pedir a un/a colega que no maneja `R` que cree la tabla de condiciones en Excel.

Un desglose comentado del join. El comentario está arriba de la línea pertinente:

```
fuzzy_left_join(
                # Del lado izq del join tus datos. 
                datos,
                # Del lado derecho la tabla de empate con las condiciones.
                intervalo, 
                # Defines explícitamente qué variables deben evaluarse. En este
                # caso la misma variable de la izquierda se evalúa contra dos
                # variables de la derecha. 
                # Caso omiso al signo igual, la función de empate se define en otra parte.
                by = c("Calification" = "piso", 
                       "Calification" = "techo"), 
                # Dos funciones de empate para dos columnas: mayor o igual para 
                # piso y menor para techo. 
                # Entonces Calificación debe ser mayor o igual a piso y menor a techo,
                # i.e. estar comprendido en ese intervalo
                match_fun = list(`>=`, `<`))
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funcionó perfecto y con tu explicación me quedó todo super claro